# Necessary files to deploy for website using linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm new @ linq and can't find anywhere where it mentions if the dbml or other files are necessary to deploy with a website.

Comment: ok, I guess all the necessary info is compiled into the <website>.dll file as I copied all the web's files to a different folder, pointed the virtual folder to the new folder, ran the web site (worked fine), then deleted the (datacontext) files, worked fine, then deleted the <website>.dll and it bombed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the Publish command on the web site. It knows what needs to be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually compiled into the dll generated for the site, so even if you deploy your site with all the files if you change any of the .cs or .vb code files directly on the deployed folder nothing changes, the only things that you can alter and change the behaviour of the website are the .aspx, .master, .css, .js (and some other non compiled files)

Notice that you deploy with the option "Only the Necessary files", those pages won't even go to the deploy directory.